# photorec not asking for file types

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to use photorec version 6.13 to recover data from my formatted hard disk. While I see that, photorec is recovering the files, (I selected the saved file location in a USB drive.) but, it did not ask me what type of files to recover. ( I only want my photos back, so, jpg is the only file type I want to recover )

But, I see there is such an option in the tutorials of photorec.

Am I doing anything wrong ? Or is there anyway to add file types to recover?

Would it be fixed if I install Photorec 6.11 ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running PhotoRec on a partition we can set the option which files to detect in the bottom menu at the time we selected the partition to search:

```
[Search] [Options] [File Opt] [Quit]
```

Select `[File Opt]` for a list of recognized formats. All file types marked will then be  recovered if possible. By default it will scan for all possible file types.

Also see [PhotoRec Step by Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step).